# What's a simple, non-jquery way to toggle between two divs using two buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for a simple, non-jquery method of toggling between two divs. Specifically, clicking button A will show div A content (and hide div B content), and clicking button B will show div B content (and hide div A content. I want div A content to appear by default when the page loads.

The code I have isn't hiding the appropriate divs from the onclick

I've looked around, but every solution seems overly complex or seems to involve jquery - which I would really prefer not to use, because I have to work with an old jquery library on a site where I shouldn't be updating that stuff.

```html
<button class="button" onclick="content_A(); Hide_Content_B;">Content A</button>
&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
<button class="button" onclick="content_B(); Hide_Content_A;">Content B</button>
<script>
  function Content_A() {
      var x = document.getElementById("A");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
          x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
          x.style.display = "none";
      }
  }
</script>
<script>
  function Hide_Content_B() {
      var x = document.getElementById("B");
      if (x.style.display === "block") {
          x.style.display = "none";
      } else {
          x.style.display = "none";
      }
  }
</script>
<script>
  function Content_B() {
      var x = document.getElementById("B");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
          x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
          x.style.display = "none";
      }
  }
</script>
<script>
  function Hide_Content_A() {
      var x = document.getElementById("A");
      if (x.style.display === "block") {
          x.style.display = "none";
      } else {
          x.style.display = "none";
      }
  }
</script>
<div id="A"> stuff</div>
<div id="B"> other stuff </div>
```

Comment: do you want to put me both `div` and `button` in a container?

Comment: Whoops - I see I forgot to add the () after the second functions of the onclicks.  Okay, so I'm almost there.  My only question left, I think, is - how do I show only the content A default the first time, but then get an either/or toggle after that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your code:

- You have to call the function using parenthesis like `Hide_Content_A()` and `Hide_Content_B();` which are misssing in onclick of the `<button>`
- The functions `Content_B` and `Content_B` start with uppercase `C`.

The fix your own code, just run `Hide_Content_B();` at the end to hide the second one.

Note that you can also use a single `<script>` block.

```js
function Content_A() {
  var x = document.getElementById("A");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function Hide_Content_B() {
  var x = document.getElementById("B");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function Content_B() {
  var x = document.getElementById("B");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function Hide_Content_A() {
  var x = document.getElementById("A");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
Hide_Content_B();
```

```html
<button class="button" onclick="Content_A(); Hide_Content_B();">Content
    A
</button> &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
<button class="button" onclick="Content_B(); Hide_Content_A();">Content
    B
</button>
<div id="A"> stuff</div>
<div id="B"> other stuff</div>
```

Comment: Woohoo! That's it!  There are some great solutions offered here, but this is the simplest.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Create **one** function `showContent` that takes the `id` of the element you want
to toggle as *parameter* and just [toggles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods) a CSS class, i.e `visible` on the element with that id.

Use [CSS classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference) to initially hide the "toggleable" elements. You can set the `visible` class directly on the element you want shown on page load.

Here's an example:

```js
function showContent(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle('visible')
}
```

```css
/* 
   All elements with class "toggleable" 
   should be hidden.
 */
.toggleable {
  display: none;
}

/* 
   All elements that have both
   class "toggleable" and "visible"
   should be visible.
 */
.toggleable.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showContent('a');" >Show Content A</button>
<button onclick="showContent('b');" >Show Content B</button>


<div class="toggleable visible" id="a">
  Hello Content A!
</div>
<div class="toggleable" id="b"> 
  Hello Content B!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use jQuery, you should consider not using javascript at all.

You can do the same with pure css. Also the styling of button tags some times brakes in other devices, so I suggest to use  tag or just a span

Here is a pure CSS solution:

```css
input {
  display:none;
}
input[name="toggle"] + .toggleContent{
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .4s;
}
input[name="toggle"]:checked + .toggleContent{
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<label for="A">A Button</label>
<input type="radio" name="toggle" value="1" id="A" checked="checked">
<div class="toggleContent">This is content for A</div>

<label for="B">B Button</label>
<input type="radio" name="toggle" value="2" id="B">
<div class="toggleContent">This is content for B</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution that requires jQuery 1.7 or above, since you mentioned that you're working with an old jQuery library!

```js
$(document).on('click', '.map-point-sm', function() {
  var show = $(this).data('show');
  $(show).removeClass("hide").siblings().addClass("hide");
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.map-container {
  text-align: center;
}
button{
  width: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="map-container">
  <div class="inner-basic division-map div-toggle" data-target=".division-details" id="divisiondetail">
    <button class="map-point-sm" data-show=".a">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="centered-y">
          <p>A</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </button>
    <button class="map-point-sm" data-show=".b">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="centered-y">
          <p>B</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="map-container">
  <div class="inner-basic division-details">
    <div class="initialmsg">
      <p>A Content here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="a hide">
      <p>A Content here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="b hide">
      <p>B Content here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some great answers here, but I think I'll probably go with The fourth bird's because it's the simplest.  Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a non-JS solution, you can use sibling input elements to perform a button toggle effect. Simply match the `for` attributes with the `id` attributes.

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
input {
  display: none;
}
input:checked + label {
  background-color: #eee;
}
label {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.container {
  display: none;
  background-color: #eee;
  order: 1;
  padding: 12px;
  width: 100%;
}
input:checked + label + .container {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="a" type="radio" name="container" checked="checked">
  <label for="a">button a</label>
  <div class="container">content a</div>
  <input id="b" type="radio" name="container">
  <label for="b">button b</label>
  <div class="container">content b</div>
</form>
```